# メソッド呼び出し時のDerefの優先度

Tags: rust

RustでDeref時の優先度について質問です。

```
pub trait T {
    fn func(self);
}

pub struct A {}

impl<'a> T for &'a A {
    fn func(self) {
        println!("impl &A");
    }
}

impl<'a> T for &'a mut A {
    fn func(self) {
        println!("impl &mut A");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A {};
    a.func();
}
```

以上のコードは実行すると

```
impl &A
```

と表示され`impl T for &A {}`の`func()`が実行されていることが確認できます。ここで`impl T for &A {}`の部分を削除すると出力が

```
impl &mut A
```

となります。つまり`a.func()`は`<&A as T>::func(&a)`と`<&mut A as T>::func(&mut a)`の両方の解釈が可能ですが、実際には前者として扱います。

これはRustが暗黙の型変換において`&mut A`よりも`&A`を優先しているように解釈したのですが、これは言語仕様で決まっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC 0048](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0048-traits.md)によっておおよそ説明できそうです。これによると、メソッド呼び出しの解決は トレイトの解決 (`METHOD_SEARCH`) とそのトレイトのレシーバ型に対する調整 (`RECONCILE`) の2段階からなるようですが、 `RECONCILE` では `&mut` よりも `&` が優先的に検索されています。

このRFCではOP主の例のように同じレシーバー型、同じトレイトに対して複数の実装があるケースを考慮していないようですが、この状況については[このSOの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)が参考になりそうです。この質問のOP主は「`&T`の`self`は、`T`の`&self`と同様に扱われる」(抄訳。おそらくミスタイプと思われたため原文の`&T`と`T`を入れ替えた)と予想しています。Accepted Answer主はOP主の予想をほぼ肯定しており、Niko Matsakis氏にもチェックしてもらったと書いてあるので、これはある程度権威的な情報源と言えるかと思います。

なお、Rust Referenceには関連する情報は今のところ執筆されていないようです。